# How can I measure how much memory each thread is using in a puma deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, benchmarking, rack, puma

In a threadsafe rails app running on puma, how can I measure how much memory each thread uses?

Answer (score -1):

Graph the memory usage of your process as you increase the number of threads.